# Google App Engine - calling new Gson() creates "java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class"

Tags: google-app-engine, gson

This works when debugging locally but once deployed any servlet call to new Gson() produces this error. I've not been able to google a fix for it. What will fix the issue?

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {    
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.getWriter().println("Service started.");
}


Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-753f125056d26ae3(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:809)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:374)
    at com.selectshotgolf.game.SelectShotServlet.doGet(SelectShotServlet.java:17)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:438)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:445)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:309)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:301)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:442)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

This also works fine locally or deployed:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {    
    new JsonObject();
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.getWriter().println("Service started.");
}
```

*Edit

I let Eclipse update itself a moment ago and after a restart I had to reset the App Engine Java Build Path. Once reset I now had the option to depend on either com.google.gson.Gson or the repackaged.

This still throws the error above:

```
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

    public <T> T fromJson(String paramName, Class<T> clazz){
        if(gson == null)
            gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();

        return gson.fromJson(req.getParameter(paramName), clazz);
    }
```

but the following code works fine remotely but with the disturbing message:

"Use of com.google.appengine.repackaged may result in your app breaking without warning."

yikes

```
import com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

    public <T> T fromJson(String paramName, Class<T> clazz){
        if(gson == null)
            gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();

        return gson.fromJson(req.getParameter(paramName), clazz);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your imports are correct?

Keep in mind that App Engine SDK contains repackaged version of Gson.

```
com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.gson.Gson
```

Add your own Gson dependency and make sure the imports point to this dependency not repackaged version.

Comment: I edited my code to reflect the import on my version of Gson. The compile is fine with this as is running on localhost. The remote bombs here once it's deployed at runtime.

Comment: In this case you may try different versions of Gson and App Engine SDK. The wrong import was solution in my case, so I am not going to remove the answer because it may help somebody.

Comment: Rolling back to a previous version seems to solve the problem. Thanks for suggesting it - 2.3.1 breaks for me - 2.2.4 appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

We faced the similar issue for some other jars. Reason was mutually conflicting jar versions of Jackson libraries needed for serialization purposes.
What We did:

1. Added enforcer plugin in our (Maven) project

```html
<plugin> 
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules><dependencyConvergence/></rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
```

2. Ran enforcer on project

   **$ mvn enforcer:enforce**
3. Took remedial steps based on enforcer's recommendations
   Given ours was a pretty big project, we had around 20 odd jars in conflicts for different versions from different dependency graphs. Attended one at a time and esp. those we had doubt at.

This paid off. We were back at running the app perfectly fine.